# How to use one backing bean for 2 JSP pages

Tags: jsf

I want to use single backing bean for 2 JSP pages.

My current flow for page1 and page2 is as follows. Now both page1 and page2 wants to use the same  backing bean to edit the objects defined in the bean.
How do I write entries in the faces-config.xml?

```
       <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/wizards/script/pag1.jsp</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>finish</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/wizards/script/page2.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
   </navigation-rule>
```

Comment: In all JSF questions, always, always post the exact JSF impl/version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use conditional navigation. see following example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>start.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>payment</from-outcome>
            <if>#{paymentController.orderQty &lt; 100}</if>
            <to-view-id>ordermore.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>payment</from-outcome>
            <if>#{paymentController.registerCompleted}</if>
            <to-view-id>payment.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>payment</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>register.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

for more information check http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/conditional-navigation-rule-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: You should advise OP on the ramifications of the scope of `PaymentController`.

Comment: The point is you don't know OP's intentions for wanting to share a single backing bean across multiple pages: If OP wants to share data, he needs a different scope; if OP wants to share functionality, he needs a different scope. Your answer should include this to be useful

Comment: Please note that OP is using JSP which is deprecated since JSF 2.0. If the OP does not explicitly state/tag anywhere that JSF 2.0 is used, then you should certainly not blindly assume that the OP is using JSF 2.0. The feature described in your answer is not available in JSF 1.x and hence your answer would be completely inappropriate.